# How can you get the "real" HttpContext within an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

Unfortunately, I need to do this.  I'm using ELMAH for my error log.  Before I route to my error.aspx view, I have to grab the default ELMAH error log so I can log the exception.  You used to be able to use

```
Elmah.ErrorLog.Default
```

However, this is now marked as obsolete.  The compiler directs me to use the method

```
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext context)
```

MVC's context is of type HttpContextBase, which enables us to mock it (YAY!).  How can we deal with MVC-unaware libraries that require the old style HttpContext?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`. It should do the trick.

Gets HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 22):

```
this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context
```