# Get root part of link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

One method in my controller returns a view which has link like `http://localhost:17000/Questionnaire/CompleteQuestionnaire?GuidToken=4815823D-3BFF-487D-AEB0-BB874AE9FBDE`
and other method returns just link like `/Questionnaire/CompleteQuestionnaire?GuidToken=4815823D-3BFF-487D-AEB0-BB874AE9FBDE`

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult ShowUrlQuestionnaire(int id)
    {
        var questionnaire = QuestionnaireRepository.GetById(id);
        var questionnaireUrl = "/Questionnaire/CompleteQuestionnaire?GuidToken=" + questionnaire.QuestionnaireId.ToString();
        return Json(questionnaireUrl, "text/html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

how can I add root part of link in `var questionnaireUrl` ?

I tried to add this method in controller

```
private string GetBaseUrl()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var appUrl = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appUrl)) appUrl += "/";

        var baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, appUrl);

        return baseUrl;
    }
```

but I got error
`Error  1   'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
How to fix it?

Comment: I don't think the error occurs in the code you show us. Do you use something like `HttpContextBase.Current` somewhere? In `QuestionnaireRepository.GetById` for example.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks a lot for link, I wrote `var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;` and now it works.

Comment: You need to add that as the answer to your own question and mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution here [How can you get the “real” HttpContext within an ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153630/how-can-you-get-the-real-httpcontext-within-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
I changed in my code

```
var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
```

and now it works.