# request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress cannot find RemoteIpAddress

Tags: c#

var remoteIpAddress = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress; 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'HttpContext' and no accessible extension method 'HttpContext' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have use 'Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides'. –

Comment: what in [tag:c#] this error comes from? [tag:asp.net]? asp.net [tag:webform]? [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]? if its .net core mvc, you could just call `HttpContext` directly (in controller) without `request`, [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: asp.net and mvc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you get the "real" HttpContext within an ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153630/how-can-you-get-the-real-httpcontext-within-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: I want to know the client ip address.

Comment: you should.. improve your question by stating what you wanted exactly, format and tag the question properly. a well written question may invite good answers. perhaps you should take a [tour] and learn [ask] for a refresher :)

Answer (score 1):

> request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress cannot find RemoteIpAddress

ASP.Net MVC allows you to access the current `HttpContext` using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` as per the answer in the other [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153683/4648586).

> I want to know the client ip address.

The answer is depends, is your app reachable directly by end user or using something in the middle such as but not limited to Load Balancer, DMZ, Reverse Proxy, or CDN.

If its the **directly reachable**, the [`HttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.8#properties) itself can provide you with IP address via `HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`. That property will return the origin of the TCP connection for the request - the immediate client.

If its the **behind something** else. You will need to know how the middleman works, most commonly use `X-Forwarded-For` header to relay the origin client IP Address. Keep in mind, that particular header can have multiple comma-separated values in it, check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For#syntax). The alternative is `Forwarded` header.

In general, you can cover your ground in checking IP address this way:

```
public string GetClientIP(HttpRequest request)
{
    string ip;
    //Checks if Forwarded header is set or not
    ip = GetForwarded(request);
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ip)) return ip;
    
    //Checks if X-Forwarded-For header is set or not
    ip = GetXForwardedFor(request);
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ip)) return ip;
    
    //Fallback: use direct client IP Address
    return request.UserHostAddress;
}

private string GetXForwardedFor(HttpRequest request)
{
    string headerValue = request.Headers.Get("X-Forwarded-For");
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue))
    {
        string[] ips = headerValue.Split(',');
        if(ips.Length > 0)
        {
            return ips.First();
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}

private string GetForwarded(HttpRequest request)
{
    string headerValue = request.Headers.Get("Forwarded");
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue))
    {
        string[] entries = headerValue.Split(',');
        if(entries.Length > 0)
        {
            string[] values = entries.First().Split(';');
            string forValue = values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("for"))
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(forValue))
            {
                string[] forSplit = forValue.Split('=');
                if(forSplit.Length == 2)
                {
                    return forSplit[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

### Note

- You can shorten the entire code using [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) and `?.` operator - however i write the long version given I dont know your .Net version.
- Do keep in mind some implementation of `X-Forwarded-For` might use different separator.
- Also, keep in mind that clients can forge `X-Forwarded-For` header too, using something like:

  ```
    curl -X GET "http://myhost/" -H "X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1"
  ```
- The "curl" exploit might also be used on `Forwarded` header too, but I havent encountered it in the wild yet.